# Checking if all elements are equal with map/fold

Tags: ocaml, higher-order-functions

Given a list of elements, like [1, 1, 1] or ["a", "a", "a"], how can I check if they're all equal using map/fold?

I tried to do something like this:

```
let eq lst = fold (=) lst
```

which doesn't compile because there's no accumulator, but I'm really not so sure what to put for the accumulator. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if you wrote it out as an ordinary function instead of using partial application? This sounds a lot like an assignment that you're supposed to figure out on your own. You should at least explain the reasoning behind your current approach.

Comment: Generally the accumulator will include the final answer as one part. For simple cases, the accumulator *is* the final answer. In your case the final answer is a boolean. Something to think about, maybe.

Comment: This is a practice test question for my exam. I am trying to do it with pattern matching right now, which I think works, but I am wondering if there is just a easy way with fold

Answer (score 2):

Well, this looks like an assignment, so I won't give you the full answer, only some hints.

- An empty list consists of equal elements (vacuous truth)
- If a list starts with `x` and all other elements are equal to `x` then all elements of the list are equal.